# How change font color of Hyperlink in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How can I change the color of Hyperlink link (font) in DataGrid in WPF (C#) ?

For now, my Hyperlink column is presented like this: (XAML)

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Width="300" Binding="{Binding link}" ContentBinding="{Binding link}" 
                         Header="Link" HeaderStringFormat="Link">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>                            
            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>                            
        </Style>                        
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**xaml**

```
 <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn  Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}">
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chocolate"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Hyperlink.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" From="Chocolate" To="BlueViolet" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**c# code**

```
   public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Customer> custdata = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        custdata.Add(new Customer() { Email = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/") });
        DG1.ItemsSource = custdata;
    }
}
public class Customer
{
    public Uri Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works for me, but when I scroll around in my datagrid, the updated(clicked) hyperlink colors seems to revert back...or hyperlinks I did not click on change color while the ones I did click on revert back to the original color.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?